# Filling missing values with mode of column relative to another column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, analytics, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 2 columnns City_Type and Vehicle_Type among many other columns. Now i have some missing values in Vehicle_Type columns which i need to impute with mode of Vehicle_Type based on City_Type. 
First i need to write a python program to get the below output. Then i need to fill the missing values in Vehicle_Type field based on the below output.

```
City_Type    Vehicle_Type
Tier1        Sedans
Tier2        Hatchback
Tier3        SUV
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use groupby and fillna with mode

```
df.groupby('City_Type').Vehicle_Type.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))
```

Comment: It don't work. Maybe my question needs to be more clear.

Comment: It don't work. Maybe my question needs to be more clear.
Sample Data:
Tier1 Sedan
Tier2 SUV
Tier3 Hatchback
Tier1 Sedan
Tier2 SUV
Tier3 Hatchback
Tier1 
Tier2 Hatchback
Tier3 
Tier1 Sedan
Tier2 
Tier3 Sedan
Tier1 Hatchback
Tier2 SUV
Tier3 SUV

I need to fill the missing values with the Mode with respect to City_Type